# Internal speakers not working although external speakers are working fine.

Tags: sound

I have IBM thinkcentre workstation, it has an internal speaker which is working fine on Windows OS,but it doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 17.04 and Fedora 26 LXDE spin, I really searched for any help or workaround online and tried some tips without luck, I wish the internal speaker will work with Linux! what is your advice?
When I plug external speakers with a sound jack it's working fine, but the internal speaker of the IBM computer doesn't work, although it's working fine when I reboot to Windows XP to test out!.
I asked the same question on Fedora forum but didn't find a good help for my issue.
https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?p=1795806&posted=1#post1795806
Regards,

Comment: I had to run Windows on this computer till I have audio on Linux, no body can help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Built-in and plugged-in speakers are often controlled by different mixer channels. Call `alsamixer` (it's in the `alsa-utils` package) and scroll through the available controls using the <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> cursor keys until you find the correct control. The volume may be tuned down (change with <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd>), or the channel muted (toggle with <kbd>M</kbd>) completely.

Be also aware that sometimes the built-in speakers are auto-muted when external ones are plugged in.

Comment: I tried some mixers like alsamixer, kmix and pulse audio mixer also, no luck.

Comment: The external speakers are not plugged in.

Comment: I had to run Windows on this computer till I have audio on Linux, no body can help with this issue?

Comment: Let me also know if someone finds any solution